# Make migrations Command

Tags: python, django, web

I just started learning django with python.while I tried the run command that is `"python manage.py make migrations"` , I see `error "module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'models'"`.
how can I fix it?(I left the code and error down. )

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",on_delete = models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
content = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytELN.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. You should know that on StackOverflow is preferred to paste the text over linking extarnal images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong syntax**

`models.models.CharField(max_length=50)`

you are calling models twice.

**Try this**

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",on_delete = models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
content = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```